# return a space-less string from a function

Tags: c, arrays, space

I have a fucntion which in it I want to return a string (i.e array of chars) with no spaces at all. This is my code, which in my understanding is not right:

```
char *ignoreSpace( char helpArr[], int length ){
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    char withoutSpace[length];
    while ( i < length ){
        /*if not a space*/
        if ( isspace( helpArr[i] ) == FALSE )
            withoutSpace[j] = helpArr[i];
        i++;
    }
    return *withoutSpace;
}
```

My intention in the line:

```
return *withoutSpace;
```

Is to return the content of the array withoutSpace so I could parse a string with no spaces at all.

Can you please tell me how can I make it any better?

Comment: For a start do not return stuff on the stack. End of function - End of contents

Comment: 1) `char *withoutSpace = malloc(length+1);... return withoutSpace;` 2)edit `helpArr`, `return helpArr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution will lose the result of `withoutSpace` when the function returns as it is only defined in that function's scope.

A better pattern would be to accept a third argument to the function which is a pointer to a `char[]` to write the result into - in much the same way the standard functions do, (eg [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

```
char* ignoreSpace(char* src, char* dst, int length) {
    // copy from src to dst, ignoring spaces
    // ...
    // ...
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: Alan - you should also note the issues @ThoAppelsin mentioned with the specific implementation that you are not incrementing j in your loop

Comment: To follow `strcpy()/strncpy()` closely, change parameter order/type.  `char* ignoreSpace(char* dst, const char* src, size_t length)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't increment `j`, ever. In the case that the current character of the source string is not a space, you probably would like to store it in your output string and then also increment the `j` by one; so that you'd store the next possible character into the next slot instead of overwriting the `0`th one again and again.

So change this:

```
...
    withoutSpace[j] = helpArr[i];
...
```

into this:

```
...
    withoutSpace[j++] = helpArr[i];
...
```

And then also append your `withoutSpace` with a `0` or `'\0'` (they are the same), so that any string processing function may know its end. Also return the pointer, since you should do that, not the `*withoutSpace` or `withoutSpace[0]` (they are the same):

```
char *ignoreSpace( char helpArr[], int length ){
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    char * withoutSpace = malloc( length * sizeof * withoutSpace ); // <-- changed this
    while ( i < length ){
        /*if not a space*/
        if ( isspace( helpArr[i] ) == FALSE )
            withoutSpace[j++] = helpArr[i]; // <-- replaced j with j++
        i++;
    }
    withoutSpace[j] = 0;    // <-- added this
    return withoutSpace;
}
```

And then you should be good to go, assuming that you can have variable-length arrays.

**Edit:** Well, variable-length arrays or not, you better just use dynamic memory allocation by using `malloc` or `calloc` or something, because else, as per comments, you'd be returning a local pointer variable. Of course, this requires you to manually `free` the allocated memory in the end.

Comment: @TheAppelsin if I return the pointer won't I be returning a pointer to a local variable?

Comment: @Alan Hah, that is correct... Well, you better just `malloc` or `calloc` it, or just alter the `helpArr` itself. Sorry for that. But if you return the `*withoutSpace`, then you'd return just one `char`, and that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming null terminated string)

```
void ignoreSpace(char *str) {
   int write_pos = 0, read_pos  = 0;
   for (; str[read_pos]; ++read_pos) {
      if (!isspace(str[read_pos]) {
         str[write_pos++] = str[read_pos];
      }
   }
   str[write_pos] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable from a function, because as soon as you leave the function all local variables are detroyed and no longer valid.

You must either

1. Allocate space with `malloc` in your function and return a pointer
   to that allocated memory
2. not return a pointer from the function butmodify directly the
   original string.

First solution :

```
char *ignoreSpace(char helpArr[], int length)
{
  int i=0; int j=0;
  char *withoutSpace = malloc(length) ;

  while(i <= length)
  {
    /*if not a space*/
    if(isspace(helpArr[i]) == FALSE)
        withoutSpace[j++] = helpArr[i];

    i++;
  }

  return withoutSpace;
}
```

Second solution:

```
char *ignoreSpace(char helpArr[], int length)
{
  int i=0; int j=0;

  while(i <= length)
  {
    /*if not a space*/
    if(isspace(helpArr[i]) == FALSE)
        helpArr[j++] = helpArr[i];

    i++;
  }

  return helpArr;
}
```

There are some other small correction in my code. Finding out which ones is left as an exercise to the reader.